# Best field type to store videos & Audios duration

Tags: 2013, list, development, administration, field-type

I am working on a custom list inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013. and the custom list will store information about videos and audios (i am not doing to upload the actual audios and videos). and I need a field to store the duration of the video or audio. so not sure which field type best achieve this? 
Currently, I define a field named `Duration (in minutes)` of type number, and I store the value as following `90` , `120` ,`30` , etc. so is using the Number field type the best option to follow? 
The main issue I am currently facing with using the Number field type, is that I cannot express the duration in a user friendly way, such as  `01:10:20`  which represents `1 hour + 10 minutes + 20 seconds`, and I do not want to have a single line text to store the value as `01:10:20` because I will not be able to query the items or sort them according to their duration values (since I will be sorting string values and not actual duration values)...

so can anyone advice on this, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The field with `NUMBER` datatype is the only suitable field to save number values whether it's `integer` values or `float` values.

> Unfortunately, There is no datatype to hold only `TIME` or `DURATION` in
> SharePoint Column.

---

**[Workaround]**

- **As an OOTB solution**, Create a calculated field that [converts the number in minutes to time](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/convert-numbers-to-time-in-sharepoint/).
- **As a Dev Solution**, Create a custom data type for time and duration format and this solution requires Dev skils.

---

**For more details, check**

- [How to Convert Numbers To Time In SharePoint Calculated Field](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/convert-numbers-to-time-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: yes i know i can have a calculated column to convert the number in minutes to the following format `hh:mm:ss` but my question was if the users can enter the data inside the fields in the following format `01:02:30` ? regards

Comment: Hahahah, , okay if you know!! share with us the formula !! also you have asked about the best field type to save duration and as I answered there is no data type that matches this format! and I have introduced two options to do that! and finaly you asked about advice! so what's your issue in the provided answers?

Comment: why you are so happy !!! i am telling you that using formula will allow me to show the value in `hh:mm:ss` but will not allow me to enter the data in this format. and my question is if sharepoint have field type to support entering data as `hh:mm:ss`, or what is the best option to do so... and you mentioned it does not have any field type to support entering duration in `hh:mm:ss` format ,,, so i was not asking for workaround or for dev solution which i am already aware of,, i am asking about field type...